# Grub Installation EFI Dual Boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

EDIT 2:  Here is the "Create BootInfo Summary" paste2.org/bY6bJDy3
     Here is the output of "fdisk -l" drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FIS-RlDuKhTERCNHZJbkdHMms

EDIT: It's not allowing me to attach images or add links since I don't have enough "reputation". The link below is to a Google Drive folder with efibootmgr output and fstab content

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FIS-RlDuKhbE9kVU5WNjR6dms

I've been trying to set-up a dual boot system on my Dell Precision 5510 for several days now using UEFI for both. Currently system will boot to Grub shell when powering on; it does not go to Windows boot loader or Grub boot loader.

I can successfully boot to Ubuntu using [these steps](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux):

```
set pager=1
set root=(hd0,gpt5)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic root=/dev/sda5
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
boot
```

That gets the OS to boot, and once inside I continued following the steps:

```
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
```

This does not provide any errors, and said installation is successful. I reboot and it just takes me back to the Grub shell. Whenever the OS had booted and I was in terminal, running `efibootmgr` shows me what I think is correct. I've attached that output. Also, I attached `/etc/fstab` which I thought also looked fine.

Does anyone know what I might be messing up here? I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure UEFI isn't the issue? I have personally had many issues with UEFI and dual-boot installs. Not to mention, it's also kind of the first thing to recommend when someone says "Ubuntu won't install next to Windows!" around here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: "Whenever the OS had booted and I was in terminal, running efibootmgr shows me what I think is correct." - could you post what efibootmgr shows you? (output of "fdisk -l" would be useful too)

Comment: snayob I can get the output of fdisk -l later tonight, I only have one machine and I'm using the Windows side to finish some homework

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Here is the "Create BootInfo Summary" http://paste2.org/bY6bJDy3

Comment: Here is the output of "fdisk -l" https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FIS-RlDuKhTERCNHZJbkdHMms

Comment: I don't know why, but I was able to fix it. From terminal I entered "sudo update-grub", then "sudo grub-install /dev/sda". Thank you everyone for your help!